# Is it possible to download files from a secure site (https) in the inno installer?

Tags: inno-setup, inno-download-plugin, inno-tools-downloader

I am working on a C# project and using Inno installer. I need to check for automatic updates in my installer and if update is available, then the installer should download the newer binaries from a secure (HTTPS) website using user authentication (e.g, from our build server).

I also checked the InnoTools Downloader (http://www.sherlocksoftware.org/page.php?id=50). It supports download from HTTP and FTP, but not from HTTPS.

Is it possible at all using inno setup file or any other installer mechanism in C#?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: This would require to modify the original library source to add a [`support for OpenSSL`](http://www.ararat.cz/synapse/doku.php/public:howto:sslplugin), but to be honest, I don't like that code.

Comment: You could make your application download the new installer instead.  That's typically more useful, as users will run the app frequently but the installer only rarely.  It does mean that the user might install it only to immediately be told that there's an update available when they actually run it, but that's not all that unusual.

Comment: Thank you TLima and Miral for the reply.

Answer (score 1):

Use **[Inno Download Plugin](http://mitrich.net23.net/?/inno-download-plugin.html)** by Mitrich Software.
It supports FTP, HTTP and HTTPS.